# Invoking install4j compiler from ant results in PermGen OutOfMemory errors

Tags: permgen, install4j

I've run into a situation where install4j v4.2.8 runs fine and generates installers when using the GUI and when invoking install4jc from the command line, but fails with the following message when invoked via the install4j ant task:

```
install4j: compilation failed. Reason: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Using visualvm, I determined that the ant task is forking a separate JVM, which appears to fail when the PermGen usage hits about 88MB. The install4j ant task docs don't say anything about being able to pass VM args (such as -XX:MaxPermSize=256MB) through to the forked JVM, but I'm wondering if that or something similar would be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the VM parameters for the command line compiler in the file [install4j installation directory]/bin/install4j.vmoptions. Just increase the -Xmx value there and add the -XX:MaxPermSize VM parameter.

Prior to install4j 5.0.7, there was a bug related to includes of relative files in .vmoptions files. For these older versions, remove the include to install4j.vmoptions in install4jc.vmoptions and add the VM parameters directly there.

Comment: Thanks. The install4jc.vmoptions file references the install4j.vmoptions file, which in turn is setting a max heap of 4GB and a MaxPermSize of 256MB. That explains why the GUI and install4jc are working. How can I tell the install4j ant task to look at either of those files?

Comment: The install4j ant task invokes install4jc.exe, so the same settings apply. Maybe the ant task is pointing at a different install4j installation?

Comment: Hmm... I'm pointing to C:\Program Files\install4j\bin\ant.jar which is within the only install4j directory on the box. Any other suggestions? Is it possible that this is a bug that's been fixed since v4.2.8?

Comment: Yes, there was a problem that was fixed in 5.0.7. Please try to remove the include to install4j.vmoptions in install4jc.vmoptions and add the VM parameters directly there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Would you like to edit your answer to include these details (difference between 4.x and 5.0.7+, etc.) or should I?